# Scrolling jquery question. How to auto scroll onclick to a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, scroll, javascript, jquery-scrollable

Just wondering if its possible to scroll to a certain div's position on a page onclick. I can't seem to find anywhere on the internet where this is documented.

My idea is to click a button, and it will take you to the position of that div on the page, possible by the div ID.

Regards,

Taylor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im not sure when you want the event to fire so here is the generic version

```
$(selector).click(function() {
   //scroll to div
});
```

If you want a `<button/>` with an id of `myButton` that when clicked will cause you to scroll to a `<div/>` with and id of `myDiv` over the course of half a second:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
   //optionally remove the 500 (which is time in milliseconds) of the
   //scrolling animation to remove the animation and make it instant
   $.scrollTo($('#myDiv'), 500);
});
```

Using the jQuery [ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need an animated scroll just use this:

```
<a href="#myID">click this</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9qJ7k/

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("#div1").scrollTop(80);
```

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/